# Expressing English modalities of advice in Latin

Tags: english-to-latin-translation, conjunctive, tenses, negation

English has expresses advice in the present and past through the use of the following modal constructions:

- present: *You **should** [...]*
- present negated: *You **shouldn't** [...]*
- past: *You **should have** [...]*
- past negated: *You **shouldn't have** [...]*

I am somewhat unsure about how to express either of these in Latin. My gut feeling for expressing the present modalities is to simply use the present subjunctive, e.g:

> *rogēs eum ut faciat prō tē illud* -- *you should ask him to do that for you*
>   *nōn trānseās illud flūmen, mī amīce* -- *you should not cross that river, my friend*

However, when it comes to expressing the past modality, I am lost. I am not even sure if the other three subjunctive tenses would work to express this.

How would one go about expressing the modalities of advice, listed above, in Latin?

Comment: Besides *debeo,* there is *oportet,* with various infinitives; and *licet* similarly.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

One way you can do this is using the verb *debeo, debere, debui, debitus*, which not only means "to owe," but also "ought/should." It's relatively simple in its construction, so lets go through each scenario you gave using the verb *amo* for the thing you should be doing.

> You should love him

So first, one puts *debeo* into the second person singular. Then, one attaches the infinitive and adds the object of the infinitive.

> *Debes amare eum* = "You ought to love him."

Likewise, for the negative, one adds *non* to this construction.

> *Debes non amare eum* = "You ought not to love him."

For expressing advice in the past, use the perfect infinitive rather than the present.

> *Debes amavisse eum* = "You ought to have loved him."
>
> *Debes non amavisse eum* = "You ought not to have loved him."

In summary, *debeo* can be used to express advice as given. There may be other ways to express these ideas, but this is the first of which I thought.

---

Specifically, the examples you gave would be translated as follows using this method:

> *Debes rogare eum ut faciat pro te illud*
>
> *Debes non transire illud flumen, mi amice*

---

As pointed out by cnread, the *non* and the time were most likely reflected in *debeo*, and not the infinitive as I stated. To adjust the last example where both are used:

> *Non debuisti amare eum*

Comment: Ēheu! Don't know how this managed to slip my mind. Grātiās tibi!

Comment: Actually, in 'unmarked' (unemphatic) usage, I think negation and indications of tense tend to be shown on the modal, not the infinitive; so *non debes eum amare* instead of *debes eum non amare*, *debuisti eum amare* instead of *debes eum amavisse*, *non debuisti eum amare* instead of *debes eum non amavisse*, etc. Indeed, Gildersleeve & Lodge 280.2.b discusses the tense issue. Allen & Greenough discusses it in 486.a and .b, noting that the present tense of debeo with perfect infinitive is used for special emphasis.

Comment: @cnread Thanks for pointing this out, I'll make an edit to reflect your comment